# snowflake string column vs date column comparison

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have 2 queries below , both return results , the first one returns correct results, the second query  compares string against date column(eff_bgn_dt), I think other databases wont allow string to date comparison, either should be string vs string or date vs date, what exactly happens with such comparison in snowflake?, compares hash value ?

```
1.select count(*)
from TableA
where  TO_DATE('20230605', 'YYYYMMDD') >eff_bgn_dt ;

 

2.select eff_bgn_dt,count(*)
from TableA
where  '20230605' >eff_bgn_dt group by eff_bgn_dt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think other databases wont allow string to date comparison,

Depending on RDBMS they allow such comparison by performing "implicit conversion" - [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

---

Snowflake [Implicit Casting (“Coercion”)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-type-conversion#implicit-casting-coercion):

> [image]

Warning - such implicit conversion may be a bit misleading because value `20230605` is not treated as 'YYYYMMDD':

```
select '20230605'::DATE;
-- 1970-08-23

select '2023-06-05'::DATE;
-- 2023-06-05
```

[DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date#usage-notes)

> **If the format of the input parameter is a string that contains an integer:**
>
> - After the string is converted to an integer, the integer is treated as a number of seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds after the start of the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 UTC).

---

The actual query:

```
select eff_bgn_dt,count(*)
from TableA
where  '20230605' > eff_bgn_dt 
group by eff_bgn_dt;

<=>

select eff_bgn_dt,count(*)
from TableA
where  '20230605'::DATE > eff_bgn_dt 
group by eff_bgn_dt;

<=>

select eff_bgn_dt,count(*)
from TableA
where  TO_DATE('1970-08-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD') > eff_bgn_dt 
group by eff_bgn_dt;
```